# php: fast conversion of varchar(32) that contains 0..9a..f to varchar ([log[38]16]+1)... 0..9A..z

Tags: php, hash, md5, logarithm

Suppose we have a string md5('somestring'). It will contain symbols 0..f. So, char(32) is OK to save that hash, but I beleive it could take no more than 21 bytes ([log 38/ log 236 + 1])*Length(hash). Any fast function to convert string with symbols 0..f into a string with symbols 0..9A..z? (which will take more than 21 bytes, because it uses only numbers and latin letters)?

Comment: So you’re actually looking for a base 16 to base 62 conversion, right? Or do you just want to know how to store a MD5 value in a database using as little storage as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Better : hash the result in binary. Binary run faster and much more faster with indexes.

With mysql create a field `bin(16)`. Query are like this :

```
    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = UNHEX('md5 hash')
```

From PHP Use this function (hex to bin)

```
    function convert($hexString)
    {
            $hexLenght = strlen($hexString);
            // only hex numbers is allowed
            if ($hexLenght % 2 != 0 || preg_match("/[^\da-fA-F]/",$hexString)) return FALSE;

            unset($binString);
            for ($x = 1; $x <= $hexLenght/2; $x++)
            {
                    $binString .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexString,2 * $x - 2,2)));
            }

            return $binString;
    }
```

You can also use : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Answer (score 0):

Set the [second parameter](http://es.php.net/md5) to true:

```
string md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```